# How to find the index of an element in a string collection using a stream in Java?

Tags: java, stream

there is a string array

```java
Integer index = null;
String [] re = {"one", "two", "three"};
      Integer size = re.length;
      for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if(re[i].equals(text)) {
                  resultIndex = i;
            }
      }
```

how rewrite this code with use stream api?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What have you tried? What has your research turned up? Why specifically using a stream? If it's for class work, your teacher or course will have gone over the necessary information, refer to your class materials and notes.

Comment: The point of using Streams here is?

Comment: Sorry. I edited the post

Comment: We don't need to do anything. You need to tell us why you would use a stream to write the above code, instead of just using the above code (or instead of `Arrays.asList(re).indexOf(text)`). Use an int for the size, BTW, not an Integer.

Comment: Ok. 
all this is a fkn pullrequest, I do not know why I'm doing this for such an elementary case (it needs to be rewritten to fashionable threads ( all may loops to stream

Comment: @JB Nizet it's easier than my option, much. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you need to use the loop index, the stream equivalent usually begins `IntStream.range`. In this case, the code looks like

```
OptionalInt index = IntStream.range(0, re.length).filter(i -> re[i].equals(text)).findFirst();
```

Despite answering your question, I do not think it is reasonable that you have been asked to go through replacing all for loops by streams. There are many cases a for loop is far simpler to read and write.

Also note that in this case there is no need to use a for loop or streams at all because you can simply do

```
int index = Arrays.asList(re).indexOf(text);
```

Comment: yes, thanks, in this case i m replace my code to ..indexOf()

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help.